# Last update of a github repo on my website

Tags: html, github, github-api

I'd like to get the date of the last update made for some of my github projects, and use these date on my site (inside a html table of projects that I list there).

Is this possible and how? Grateful for help!

PS: Not sure if this makes a difference, but my site is an "organization site" hosted on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the GitHub API (V3) to get when your repository was last pushed. For example, for the repo "km-Poonacha/testissues" i can find the last push date by making the following request `https://api.github.com/repos/km-Poonacha/testissues`. The JSON response has the field "pushed_at".